# serialize form to json with numeric values

Tags: html, jquery, json, forms

so this is commonly asked question, but I have not found how to create a json body from a form, without the quotes on the value but in the property.

I want to create a JSON body that looks like this.

```
{
"salary1":20100,
"salary2":1000,
"bill":50000
}
```

But all my attempts is returning either both property and values with or without quotes, never like I need to have.

This is what I have

```
<form action="#" method="post">
    <div>
        <label for="name">Salary1</label>
        <input type="number" name="salary1" id="salary1" value=25000  data-value-type="number"  />
    </div>
    <div>
        <label for="salary2">Salary2</label>
        <input type="number" name="salary2" id="salary2" value=18200 data-value-type="number"   />
    </div>
    <div>
        <label for="Bill">Bill</label>
        <input type="number" name="bill" id="bill" value=35000  data-value-type="number"  />
    </div>
    <p>
        <input type="submit" value="Send" />
    </p>
</form>

jQuery.fn.serializeObject = function() {
  var arrayData, objectData;
  arrayData = this.serializeArray();
  objectData = {};

  $.each(arrayData, function() {
    var value;

    if (this.value != null) {
      value = this.value;
    } else {
      value = '';
    }

    if (objectData[this.name] != null) {
      if (!objectData[this.name].push) {
        objectData[this.name] = [parseFloat(objectData[this.name])];
      }

      objectData[this.name].push(parseFloat(value));
    } else {
      objectData[this.name] = value;
    }
  });

  return objectData;
};
```

Output

```
var data = $(this).serializeObject({parseNulls: true, parseNumbers: true});
    console.log("-->serializeObject",data)
```

This returns

```
{ salary1: "25000", salary2: "18200", bill: "35000"}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're simply missing a `parseFloat` call in the `else` branch of your code - without it it's adding the contents of the field which is always a string!

```js
jQuery.fn.serializeObject = function() {
  var arrayData, objectData;
  arrayData = this.serializeArray();
  objectData = {};

  $.each(arrayData, function() {
    var value;

    if (this.value != null) {
      value = this.value;
    } else {
      value = '';
    }
    
    if (objectData[this.name] != null) {
      if (!objectData[this.name].push) {
        objectData[this.name] = [parseFloat(objectData[this.name])];
      }

      objectData[this.name].push(parseFloat(value));
    } else {
      objectData[this.name] = parseFloat(value); // <-- Missing parseFloat was here
    }
  });

  return objectData;
};

$('form').submit(function(){
  var data = $(this).serializeObject({parseNulls: true, parseNumbers: true});
  console.log("-->serializeObject",data);
  return false
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="#" method="post">
    <div>
        <label for="name">Salary1</label>
        <input type="number" name="salary1" id="salary1" value=25000  data-value-type="number"  />
    </div>
    <div>
        <label for="salary2">Salary2</label>
        <input type="number" name="salary2" id="salary2" value=18200 data-value-type="number"   />
    </div>
    <div>
        <label for="Bill">Bill</label>
        <input type="number" name="bill" id="bill" value=35000  data-value-type="number"  />
    </div>
    <p>
        <input type="submit" value="Send" />
    </p>
</form>
```

Comment: Thank! but this is so weird. it looks perfect in the snippet you did, but my rendering is coming out like this. When adding parseFloat to value.

 {salary1: 25000, salary2: 18200, bill: 35000}

Comment: @Dymond Maybe try `JSON.stringify` the result and see if that works

Comment: @Dymond also what do you mean by "my rendering"? It might just be how whatever you're using is representing the data. ie `console.log` wraps keys in quotes, but other things might not (note that there's no quotes anywhere in the creation of `objectData`)

Comment: As far as _Javascript_ is concerned `{foo:1}` and `{"foo":1}` are the same thing. JSON dictates that only the latter of those 2 examples is valid.

Comment: yeah! You are correct!. because when I check the console.log from your snippet, its looks just like mine, while the result from you snippet looks different. 
Have this been the problem all time, omg I have spent hours.

Comment: Ha yeah I just noticed the SO console and the chrome console show them differently. My point exactly though - its up to the rendering layer to decide how to represent a javascript object